# Some yasnippets don't load anymore

Tags: yasnippet

I recently upgraded to yasnippet 0.10.0, on emacs 24.5.1/OS X and noticed that some of my yasnippets are not loaded anymore, but this only affects some. I can see that these are still in the compiled list of snippet, but entering the snippet key and TAB doesn't do anything anymore.

I tried reloading and recompiling the list of yasnippets, but didn't have any luck.

One of the snippets that doesn't work anymore looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: function
# key: lerj
# --
error_log(json_encode($0));
```

My yasnippet setup:

```
(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/Documents/playground/emacs/my-emacs-config/yasnippet-snippets"))
```

In the compiled file `.yas-compiled-snippets.el` I can also see that the snippet is registered:

```
("lerj" "lerj\n$0" "function" nil nil nil "/Users/max/Documents/playground/emacs/my-emacs-config/yasnippet-snippets/php-mode/log-error-json_encode" nil nil)
```

But also when executing `yas-describe-tables` only 2 snippets are liseted, but not the `lerj` one.

I only noticed that behaviour since I upgraded yasnippet to a more recent version, but I couldn't find any similar bug report.

Comment: Do you have any other snippets named `function`? Perhaps it's being overwritten.

Comment: @npostavs thank you that was the hint, i had `name: function` copy/pasted in some other templates, previously this wasn't an issue apparently, now they stopped working. Fixed that, thanks! If you want to write an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading a new snippet with the same name as an older one will overwrite the older one.  A similar issue is [#548](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/548#issuecomment-68224840):

> > I'm not sure if having 2 snippets with the same name is supposed to work.
>
> It isn't. Two snippets with the same key is fine though, and the name
>   differentiates them.

Another way to differentiate snippets is with the `uuid` attribute. Loading a new snippet with the same name as an older one, but different `uuid` should not overwrite the older one.

So make sure your snippets have unique `name` or `uuid` attributes.